# Apache camel unmarshalling text file to Java Object

Tags: java, arraylist, apache-camel, unmarshalling, bindy

[text data file, it shows ? mark there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V43uZ.jpg)

```
Unexpected / unmapped characters found at the end of the fixed-length record at line : 1

 text file is having list of body items each length 1288, when giving single line of body record it is passing with length 1287.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Reading the error, looks like the text file contains records of 1287 characters, but the program is expecting records of 1288 characters.
To fix the problem, you can either change the record length in the program and ensure that the program can handle records of different lengths
or add a padding character to the end of each record in the text file using similar class:

```
class AddPadding {

    public static void addPadding(File file) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        List<String> records = new ArrayList<>();
        String record;
        while ((record = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            records.add(record);
        }
        reader.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
            records.set(i, records.get(i) + " ");
        }

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        for (String r : records) {
            writer.write(r);
            writer.newLine();
        }
        writer.close();
    }

    public void addPaddingToMyFile() throws IOException {
        File file = new File("textdatafile.txt");
        AddPadding.addPadding(file);
    }
}
```

This will add a padding character to the end of each record in the file textdatafile.txt.